# Wordpress Query on multiple post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am completely stumped on this. The code below allows me to query multiple post types. I break them down like this because of the use of categories. The weird thing is, I only get posts from the post_type = 'post'. The final query I use post__in to establish the posts that I want by ID. If I print out $post_ids, I get the exact IDs that I am looking for. But my final query doesn't give me those IDs. Thoughts??

```
$postArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => '16,17,18',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$videoArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'occ-videos',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$photoArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'occ-photography',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);



$docArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'wpfb_filepage',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);


$posts_query = get_posts($postArgs);
$docs_query = get_posts($docArgs);
$video_query = get_posts($videoArgs);
$photo_query = get_posts($photoArgs);


// start putting the contents in the new object
$all_posts = array_merge($posts_query, $docs_query, $video_query, $photo_query);

$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $all_posts, 'ID' );//Just get IDs from post objects

print_r($post_ids);


$artArgs = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'post__in',
    'post__in' => $post_ids);


$artQuery = get_posts($artArgs);
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that Wordpress always defaults to the post_type of post. So it's only finding posts that have one of those IDs – and ignoring your custom post types.

Trying adding a line to to your `$artArgs`

```
$artArgs = array(
  'post_type' => array('post','page','occ-videos','occ-photography'), //Add this line
  'posts_per_page' => 20,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'orderby' => 'post__in',
  'post__in' => $post_ids
);
```

And add whatever post types you need Wordpress to query.